# How can a return flight from A to B cost 1000 euros, while the same flights from B to A cost 500 euros?

Tags: airlines, price

Why is a return flight from JFK to Brussels a 1000 euros and a return flight from Brussels to JFK 500 euros?

My girlfriend is American and I'm Belgian so we fly over a lot. Every time she wants to come see me she ends up paying roughly double of what I'm paying. And this is for every single time of the year, why is this?

Comment: You can look at the fare conditions of each direction on ITA, the fare of the Belgium-originating flight will probably hase an origin restriction. There are however cases where the same fare applies both ways, for example on AF/KLM between France and Japan (which is good for me).

Comment: Bite the bullet and get a one-way for her, then start buying Brussels-JFK-Brussels for her as well.